# PHP MySql Insert n rows at once?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I **optimize** this code?

```
$items[0] = "Item-0";
$items[1] = "Item-1";
$items[2] = "Item-2";
$items[3] = "Item-3";
...
$items[n] = "Item-n";

foreach($items as $item) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (item) VALUES ('$item')");
}
```

The array is just sample and the key point I like to know is how can I insert *n* items without querying *n* times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use mulitvalue insert statements

```
 insert into mytable(item) values('item1'),('item2') etc
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`item`) VALUES ('value 1'), ('value 2'), ('value 3')
```

Form it using

```
$t = array("value 1", "value 2", "value 3");

$query = "('";
$query .= implode( "'), ('", $t);
$query .= "')";

echo $query;
```

Outputs `('value 1'), ('value 2'), ('value 3')`

Now all you need to do is stick your original query into that output.

Answer (score 1):

[user187291's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806475/php-mysql-insert-n-rows-at-once/1806486#1806486) is correct, however I wouldn't just built one massive query string.

After say 10 lots of values, I'd run an insert. It would seem less likely to fail that way then sending a possible huge query to MySQL

```
$query = '';

foreach($items as $key => $item) {

     if ($key % 10) {
        // Reset and insert
     }



}
```